# Using concat with number values

Tags: xslt-1.0

The problem is I want to present two numbers that are stored as strings nicely in a file I generate.

The following code works just fine, but the formatting is not really the one I would like it to be:

```
<xsl:call-template name="create-cell">

<xsl:with-param name="value" select="concat($value_one,' or ',$value_two)" />
```

So I thought that I'll add a format-number function and give the numbers the format I want them to have. In order to do so I cast the string to number, use the function and then cast back to string, like this:

```
<xsl:call-template name="create-cell">

<xsl:with-param name="value" select="concat(string(format-number(number($value_one), "###,###.00"),' or ',$value_two)" />
```

But the transformation ends without results (an error occurs). What exactly am I doing wrong when changing the type?

EDIT:

The error that occurs is:

```
Element type "xsl:with-param" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"
```

I guess the solution is to escape the double quotas with &quot ...

Comment: Please post enough code (XML + XSLT) to enable us reproduce the problem, and show us what the desired result is.

Comment: As seen in the comment below my answer, I misread the description of the result. If it is indeed an error, please show the exact error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part :

```
<xsl:with-param name="value" select="concat(string(format-number(number($value_one), "###,###.00"),' or ',$value_two)" />
```

should be written as:

```
<xsl:with-param name="value" select="concat(format-number($value_one, '#,###.00'), ' or ', $value_two)"/>
```

Whether that's a good approach to solve the actual problem (of which we know practically nothing) is another question.

Comment: Precisely that. It helps with the error in the post :p

Answer (score 1):

> But the transformation ends with result -

My guess is that `$value_one` is not a number. Perhaps it is formatted as `12,345.00`? If the conversion to an `xs:double` fails, it will return `NaN`, which is a valid number, but not really. Using the `format-number` function, it *should* return `NaN`, regardless the picture string.

If your variable holds the empty sequence, `format-number` will return the empty sequence.

Since `format-number` already returns a string, using `string()` on the result will have no effect.

If the `-` in your question meant a literal minus-sign, then perhaps update your question with what your first snippet and second snippet return *exactly*, and what processor (exact version) you use.

### Update (after you posted the error)

Your XSLT is not valid XML. All XSLT must be valid XML to begin with. [Michael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32563777/111575) shows where it goes wrong: an attribute value must be enclosed in quotes, and yours wasn't.

Comment: The way I asked the final question was very misleading - there is no "-" sign in the result, but an error occurs while transforming.

Comment: @Max, I updated my answer, but Michael beat me to it, he shows you the XML syntax error.